# ¿Porque no me carga los estilos en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

resulta que no me carga los estilos cuando produzco el "asset" de blade, pero si me los carga cuando voy más atrás , ejemplo :

```
<link href="../resources/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Aquí me carga los estilos pero si produzco esto :

```
    <link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

No me carga nada , a que se debe esto y como podría solucionarlo? de antemano muchas gracias!  , Agregare imagenes de referencia(pd:estoy trabajando con laravel) :

[image: Imagen representativa]

Este es lo que me indica cuando ejecuto npm run dev :
[image: Imagen]

Y aqui esta la imagen de mi package.json :

[image: package]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los archivos ubicados en `resources` deben compilarse con [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix), para esto debes tener Node.js instalado, y ejecutar `npm install` para instalar las dependencias de NPM y `npm run dev` (u otro script, revisa el archivo `package.json` para más información) para compilar los recursos JavaScript, SASS, etc. Con esto tendrás los estilos y scripts ubicados en `public` y accesibles con `public_path` o `asset`.

Comment: Gracias por comentar don_aman , lo produje  todo y en el npm run dev , tambien cargo pero se quedo pegado y no me deja escribir(estoy produciendolo con el cmd del sistema) , agregare la imagen del cmd y tambien lo que hay en el package.json, en el cmd no me deja escribir nada y es como si hubiera quedado pegado

Comment: @LuisCifuentes ah, según tu `package.json`, el script `dev` inicia un servidor de desarrollo que se refresca con los cambios en `resources`. Si solo quieres compilar los recursos usa el script `build`, con `npm run build`.

Comment: Pd , como puedo dejar en negrita ciertos comentarios , de antemano muchas gracias !